# Python and webkit Qt4

Tags: python, qtwebkit

i'm trying to show a webpage in a frame, but i can't figure out how to do it, also because i can't find the right documentation and/or tutorial for the QtWebkit.

Thanks.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWebKit

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.resize(350, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle('MainWindow')

        self.statusBar().showMessage('Loading...')

        self.web = QtWebKit.QWebView()
        self.web.load(QtCore.QUrl('google.com'))
        self.web.show()

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
main = MainWindow()
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

for some doc, you can try the riverbank [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwebview.html) (though code examples are still in C…)

It seems that your code is fine (maybe add `http://`?. But did you try to do that without classes? This should work:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("http://google.com"))
web.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Otherwise, there is a problem somewhere else (a proxy maybe?)

Comment: Ok, thanks very match, this works (without classes). Now the next step is the following: i want to go to maps.gogle.com (or sort of) and when i click on the map i want to save latitude longitude (2 numbers in decimal like 47.3421, -0.9892) of every click... is that possible? Thanks